# Crystal Report Export & Print Button not working in Crystal report Viewer 13.0.

Tags: export, crystal-reports-2010

I am using crystal report 13.0. The in build print button is not working in Mozilla Firefox and Chrome. But, that is working fine in internet explorer.

Can any one help me.

Comment: try to set printmode to 'pdf', then print button should be able to work. but i have  [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206230/)